# how to post back while clicking on table rows-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a dynamically created table in my view. Each table have a hidden field and that have a unique id.

I need a post back while user click on table rows and i must get corresponding hidden field value in controller.

How can i post back while user click on rows.

Answer (score 3):

Finally got the answer.Just catch the table row click event and submit the form.The code is shown below

in view

```
    //script

   <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {         
     $('#resultTable tr').click(function (event) {            
         $('#myform').submit();
      });
 });
</script>
 //use beginform
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" })) 
   { %>
       <table width="100%"  id="resultTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       //rows here
      </table>
      <% } %>
```